# How to show SharePoint List views last 6 months or last year statistics

Tags: list, item, statistics

Good day,
I have SP list. I must get this list items usage data for 2020 year. This is 2020 year statistics about list items viewing.
I can show popularity trends on page by managed properties ViewsLastMonths1, ViewsLastMonths2, ViewsLastMonths3 https://tantumpoint.wordpress.com/2017/10/03/sharepoint-search-get-usage-data-from-search/
But how can I get information about views last 6 months or 12 months ?
Is it possible to create managed property ViewsLastMonths6 or ViewsLastMonths12 ?
My script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 
 var titleLabel=[];
 var titleView=[];
 
 $.ajax({
 url: "<MY SITE>/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:<MY SITE>/Lists/1/+ContentClass:STS_ListItem+ContentClass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary'&selectproperties='Title,path,ViewsLifeTime,ViewsLastMonths3,ViewsLastMonths3Unique'&rowlimit=5000",
 
 type: "GET",
 headers: {
 "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
 },
 success: function(data) {
 //log the json to analyze and visualize

 var items=data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;

 //log the actual 10 items that is going to be displayed
 //console.log(items);
 
 var i=0;
 
    var data = [];
 
 $.each(items, function(index, item) { 
 
 var ret= items[index].Cells.results[6].Value;
 
 var title = keyValue(this, 'Title');
 
  var ViewsLastMonths3 = keyValue(this, 'ViewsLastMonths3');
  
   var ViewsLastMonths3Unique = keyValue(this, 'ViewsLastMonths3Unique');
 
 
 //replacing any spaces in the URL
 var itemlinks= ret.replace(/ /g,"%20");

            data.push({title: title, ViewsLastMonths3:ViewsLastMonths3, ViewsLastMonths3Unique:ViewsLastMonths3Unique, itemlinks:itemlinks});
 });
 
 
 // To show 10 most popular items last 3 Months
 data.sort(function(a, b){  
    return b.ViewsLastMonths3-a.ViewsLastMonths3
    })
  $.each(data, function(i,v){
      if (i<10){
             titleLabel.push(v.title);
         titleView.push(v.ViewsLastMonths3);
         $('#popular tr:last').after('<tr><td><a target="_blank" class=itemtitle href='+v.itemlinks+'>'+v.title+'</a></td><td>'+ v.ViewsLastMonths3 +'</td><td>' + v.ViewsLastMonths3Unique + '</td></tr>');
         i++;
      }
});
 
}
 });
 
 
    function keyValue(row, fldName) {
        var ret = null;
        $.each(row.Cells.results, function () {
            if (this.Key == fldName) {
                ret = this.Value;
            }
        });
        return ret;
    } 
 });
 
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: SharePoint 2016

Answer (score 0):

Those statistics are only kept for 90 days by default.  You can update the value with PowerShell.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1cd8d0e1-82f7-4472-be77-de02ded1ebf0/sharepoint-2013-audit-log-and-max-period-for-retention?forum=sharepointgeneral

Comment: Thanks for reply, but then I don't understand, how can SharePoint create Audit Log Report for custom Date range if it keeps statistics 90 days only? I say about Site Collection Administration -> Audit Log Reports -> Executing a custom report. For example, I can create this Audit Report for May 2020. I must show this information on Sharepoint Page for all users.